# Property does not exist on type string | object typescript

Tags: typescript

I am getting folwing error Property 'p' does not exist on type 'string | { p: string; }'
can someone help me to resolve it?

```
interface x{
    n:string | {p:string}
}

function text(args:x){
    const {n:{p}}=args;
    console.log(p);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say `type WithP = { p: string }`.
The type of `n` is `string | WithP`. It means that the values for the property `n` either belongs to set of `string` or `WithP`. Since there is no overlap between these two sets (types), the values for `n` can not lie in both the sets simultaneously.

While destructuring, the actual type for `n` is not yet known, that is, the property `p` may or may not exist on `n`. To make sure that `n` has property `p`, you need to do [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

```
interface WithP {
    p: string
}

interface x {
    n: string | WithP
}

function text(args: x){
    const { n: { p }} = args;
    console.log(p);
}

function text2(args: x){
    const { n } = args;

    // type narrowing
    if (typeof n === "string") {
        // values for `n` are strings now
        console.log(n)
    } else {
        // values for `n` are WithP's now
        const { p } = n;
        console.log(p);
    }

}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwArIN4BQyxyADgFzIDOYUoA5gQL4EGiSyIoAe+RJISjToh6yAD5oMOZqxgBXEAjDAA9iGSRuYABRwo9KpW4BKQiWQJ1NfMkG3SyJk2QBeZPsMBufsSsgqVQAbCAA6INV6HVITHxYCBSUVdU0IbQAmPQMjZFNzEn8bPDsnNw9sn19kAHpqzQBPUhQQfShVAHcGKuAYZB0wRohVXo1XMeQAImEGCZM+Cwta5AA3OCD5CCpkGFUoZAADEH3ylGnRLZAOqotC4LCIqJATKpcIIKoUfIWautX1ze2uwORxOUiw2AA5Bcrt8-NYwA5Su4QD5YZZrHdwpForEXqwmEA)